# Append encoding information to HTTP response headers

Tags: apache, content-encoding

I have an old web application (not maintained anymore) of which a small part is still needed; this is displayed in iframes.

Unfortunately, the old application uses `ISO-8859-1` encoding (which it doesn't declare; it simply sends `Content-Type: text/html`), while the new one (of course) uses `UTF-8`.  Thus, since the encoding of the iframe contents is not specified, `UTF-8` is expected, and thus several characters look wrong.

The VirtualHost of the old application does some rewriting to a JBoss application:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:9080/$1 [L,P]
```

I'm able to edit this `VirtualHost` (while nobody will touch the application itself anymore); how would I add the encoding information?

E.g., for all contents with a textual content type *which lack encoding information* (naked `Content-Type: text/html`), append `; charset: ISO-8859-1`.
Any simple code snippet?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP header you need to add is `Content-Type: text/html; charset: ISO-8859-1`.

---

You can add FilesMatch and other directives within the Apache `<VirtualHost>` declaration:

```
<VirtualHost>
  # other directives here such as DocumentRoot
  <FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
    Header always set Content-Type "text/html; charset: ISO-8859-1"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
    AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
    Header always set Content-Type "text/css; charset: ISO-8859-1"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
    Header always set Content-Type "text/javascript; charset: ISO-8859-1"
  </FilesMatch>
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:9080/$1 [L,P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: As I said, I won't touch the old application, so neither the PHP nor the HTML hint applies. And I don't serve out of a directory structure, so `.htaccess` doesn't apply, either. I need to add the `charset` information for textual content (e.g. not for images), and of course only unless already given.

Comment: I've edited the solution to explain that the PHP/HTML snippets are a secondary fallback method, and that the Header can be set from within the VirtualHost declaration too, not just from within .htaccess files.

Comment: Yes, but not everything is HTML text - there are images as well. So I need to affect `text/html` only. (There *might* even be pages which *have* the charset defined.) Wouldn't this `Header always set` part overwrite e.g. `image/png` types?

Comment: I've modified the solution following your comment to show how directives can be nested inside the VirtualHost declaration, without seeing your current VirtualHost code it is very hard to try and replicate but hopefully the snippet above is close enough for you to customise how you need.

Comment: Thanks für the hint to [AddDefaultCharset](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#AddDefaultCharset); it seems to do everything I need (no further filtering necessary).